# Had Shechem ben Chamor been a 1st born would he have required to be redeemed by using a sheep?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Exodus 34:20:

> וּפֶ֤טֶר חֲמוֹר֙ תִּפְדֶּ֣ה בְשֶׂ֔ה וְאִם־לֹ֥א תִפְדֶּ֖ה וַעֲרַפְתּ֑וֹ

The first born of Chamor should be redeemd with a sheep, and if it is not redeemed, you should break its neck.

In Breishit 34, we read about Shechem, the son of Chamor wwoing Dina, the daughter of Ya'akov. We don't know if Shechem was Chamor's first born, but, if he were, would he require either redemption using a sheep (instead of 5 silver shekalim) or breaking his neck if he refused to be exchanged for the sheep?

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Chamor tried to be a wolf in sheep's clothing through his two faced deal with Binei Yisroel. Since he offered no actual sheep, he was liable for  (and received) a broken neck...

Answer (score 1):

His father was Chamor and not his mother so he was not peter rechem Chamor. If his mother was also a (female) donkey, then he would not have been killed with the sword. Since Levi was the one who killed him (the progenetor) of kohanim, obviously he paskened that Shechem did not have to have his neck broken.